# How to list partition-pruned inputs for Hive tables?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark SQL to query data in Hive. The data is partitioned and Spark SQL correctly prunes the partitions when querying.

However, I need to list either the source tables along with partition filters or the specific input files (`.inputFiles` would be an obvious choice for this but it does not reflect pruning) for a given query in order to determine on which part of the data the computation will be taking place.

The closest I was able to get was by calling `df.queryExecution.executedPlan.collectLeaves()`. This contains the relevant plan nodes as `HiveTableScanExec` instances. However, this class is `private[hive]` for the `org.apache.spark.sql.hive` package. I think the relevant fields are `relation` and `partitionPruningPred`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

**Update:** I was able to get the relevant information thanks to Jacek's suggestion and by using `getHiveQlPartitions` on the returned `relation` and providing `partitionPruningPred` as the parameter:

```
scan.findHiveTables(execPlan).flatMap(e => e.relation.getHiveQlPartitions(e.partitionPruningPred))
```

This contained all the data I needed, including the paths to all input files, properly partition pruned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're asking for low-level details of the query execution and things are bumpy down there. *You've been warned :)*

As you noted in your comment, all the execution information are in this `private[hive] HiveTableScanExec`.

One way to get some insight into `HiveTableScanExec` physical operator (that is a Hive table at execution time) is to create a sort of backdoor in `org.apache.spark.sql.hive` package that is not `private[hive]`.

```
package org.apache.spark.sql.hive

import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveTableScanExec
object scan {
  def findHiveTables(execPlan: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan) = execPlan.collect { case hiveTables: HiveTableScanExec => hiveTables }
}
```

Change the code to meet your needs.

With the `scan.findHiveTables`, I usually use `:paste -raw` while in `spark-shell` to sneak into such "uncharted areas".

You could then simply do the following:

```
scala> spark.version
res0: String = 2.4.0-SNAPSHOT

// Create a Hive table
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
spark.catalog.createTable(
  tableName = "h1",
  source = "hive", // <-- that makes for a Hive table
  schema = new StructType().add($"id".long),
  options = Map.empty[String, String])

// select * from h1
val q = spark.table("h1")
val execPlan = q.queryExecution.executedPlan
scala> println(execPlan.numberedTreeString)
00 HiveTableScan [id#22L], HiveTableRelation `default`.`h1`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [id#22L]

// Use the above code and :paste -raw in spark-shell

import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.scan
scala> scan.findHiveTables(execPlan).size
res11: Int = 1
```

`relation` field is the Hive table after it's been resolved using `ResolveRelations` and `FindDataSourceTable` logical rule that Spark analyzer uses to resolve data source and hive tables.

You can get pretty much all the information Spark uses from a Hive metastore using `ExternalCatalog` interface that is available as `spark.sharedState.externalCatalog`. That gives you pretty much all the metadata Spark uses to plan queries over Hive tables.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the relevant information using `getHiveQlPartitions` on the returned `relation` and providing `partitionPruningPred` as the parameter:

`scan.findHiveTables(execPlan).flatMap(e => e.relation.getHiveQlPartitions(e.partitionPruningPred))`

This contained all the data I needed, including the paths to all input files, properly partition pruned.

It's unfortunate that low-level package private access is required for this and standard `inputFiles` doesn't do that itself though. I assume that's for performance reasons?